# the returnValue of my Stringbuilder is not loeded into the String I want to send as an extra, why?

Tags: android

I have a function `getConfiguration(char type)`. depending on a selected option,  a certain character like 'A' or 'M'or sent to `getConfiguration(char type)`. my `getconfiguration` builds a long string and depending on the type one part of will be executed:

```
getConfiguration(char type){
    String allConfig = "";

    allConfig += "BEGIN\n";
    if (type=='A'||type=='M'){
        ....
    }

    if (type=='A'||type=='X'){
        ...
    }

     allConfig += "ENDE";

    return allConfig;
}
```

A is the complete list and everything works well for A but for all other options although I get dataConfig: //parameters are correctly changed
for the string in which I want to save it this whole part of the function is not executed. and I get for:
String result=dataConfig.getConfig(...) 
result =" BEGIN\nEND

any ideas what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say class A costructs the class Config that includes the getConfig() and then sends the answer to class B. for that it uses:

putExtra("tagForValue",Value);

when the string is modified in class B the answer should be also sent back using the same putExtra

my problem was I was sending it back again. but still not getting any errors, because I had used the same "tagForValue" so often it was using another Extra.

I hope this helps some other beginner like me!